# Relative clauses with prepositions

Tags: prepositions, free-relative-clauses, content-clauses

I'd like to know if the following sentence is correct:

> I took care **of where** you will sleep.

On one hand, the part *of where* sounds strange to me, but on the other hand, I can't think of a grammar rule that would forbid that.

Is it correct to say that? Wht? Why not?

Comment: "Where you will sleep" is an [interrogative content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause). Its use here seems okay to me, but I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score 4):

This is fine.

A relative clause which is not "bound" to a noun which it modifies (and which is therefore sometimes called a *free* relative clause) acts syntactically like a noun: it can be a subject or object of a verb, or the object of a preposition.

> SUBJECT: **Where you will sleep** is on the couch.
>   OBJECT of VERB: I want to know **where you will sleep**.
>   OBJECT of PREPOSITION: I took care of **where you will sleep**.